# Pipe current w3m buffer into new neomutt email

Tags: mutt, lynx, links, w3m, neomutt

I am a very satisfied user of w3m and neomutt, both as separate applications, and with w3m being the default viewer for html emails within neomutt.

One aspect that has remained elusive for me however has been the ability to use a some kind of hotkey function to capture the text of a w3m buffer and send it as an email text via neomutt.

As an alternative to placing the text only buffer into the body of the email itself, a saved plain text copy of the buffer as an attachment would also work fine.

My work flow up until this point has been to

1. Manually save the current w3m buffer as plain text using Shift+S.
2. Manually start a new email in neomutt, filling in the recipient address, subject etc.
3. Conclude the email and then attach the saved *.txt file to the email before sending.

However this requires quite some fiddling around if one intends to send links regularly (as I do). Ideally I would like to be able to press a series of hot keys, or run a script to capture the buffer and automatically start a new email containing the contents of the buffer.

Any information or tips on how to do this in an automated fashion would be very appreciated. If it is of importance, I am using ksh on OpenBSD. If there is no way to do this using w3m, I am open to alternate solutions using other text-only browsers such as lynx or links.

NB: There are GUI browser solutions that simply capture and share the weblink via another GUI standalone mail application. I would like a way to send the entire text of the webpage (whether in-line or as an attachment).